# How to fix "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location" in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, reactjs, jetbrains-ide, eslint

How to fix `react/jsx-closing-bracket-location` issue in WebStorm(Idea, PhpStorm, etc)?

The problem:

```
 getElem(name) {
    return (<input type="text"
      value={this.state.value}
    />);
  }
```

This block will produce an error:

> The closing bracket must be aligned with the opening tag (expected
>   column 13)                  react/jsx-closing-bracket-location

(docs for [react/jsx-closing-bracket-location](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-closing-bracket-location.md))

Same block without that problem:

```
 getElem(name) {
    return (<input type="text"
      value={this.state.value}
            />);
  }
```

P.S. I'm not allowed to modify `eslint` rules

Comment: If you are using tslint plugin, you may override options in your tslint.json. Your link describes how to do...

Comment: @Karbos538 I knew it. But I can't write code in other way than the rest of the team. So it's not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't configure WebStorm to automatically format your code according to this rule, here's a related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19721

But WebStorm won't break your formatting if you already have a code formated like that.

You can either format it like that manually or use ESLint --fix option (hit alt-enter on the error and select Fix with ESLint or run `eslint --fix filename` in the terminal).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same problem. Here was my code:

```
 <input
    className="input__field input__field--haruki"
    type="text" id="input-1"
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}/>
```

To work I did that:

```
 <input
    className="input__field input__field--haruki"
    type="text" id="input-1"
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
 />
```

Just created a new line with the /> aligned with the original tag.